# How can I encode a string in Java to use as a filename?

Tags: java, android

I'm receiving a string from an external process.I want to use that String to call a filename.
How can I safely encode the String so that it can be used as a filename?

Comment: Well, Please specify the format of the string. Its not clear question.

Comment: is that normal string or is being encoded?

Comment: If you have a string, it means you've already encoded your file.

Comment: no this normalthis is my code:String str1 = "one"; and this is what i want to use:ib16.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);

Comment: You mean you would like to translate a string into a resource id?

Comment: At runtime, that is no longer a file.

Comment: yes this is what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Resource#getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String str1 = "one";
int resourceId= getResources().getIdentifier(str1, "drawable", getPackageName());
ib16.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

You should also check returned value from getIdentifier() (0 in case if resource was not found) and handle error gracefully.